# Skipping do/while loop

Tags: javascript, node.js, loops, null, do-while

Hey guys I'm writing an algorithm to remove concrete branches(sth like DSF) from NodeTree. If you choose the name of the node algorithm is checking if this node is a parent for another ones; if yes it takes children of this node and also add to stack and so on. Hopefully code is presenting that.

The problem is that loop do/while is being executed twice when I think it should be executed once. Something is happening with null condition inside while, because it is skipped.

```
  stack.push(keys.head);
    // visited.push(flag.data);
    while(stack.size>0){
        stackTemp=stack.get()

        stack.pop();
        do{
          values=stackTemp.next;
          stack.push(values);
          stackTemp=values.next;
          stack.show();

        }while (!stackTemp)
        stackTemp=stack.get()
        // console.log(stackTemp);
        keyTemp=this.map.get(stackTemp.data);
        if(keyTemp=undefined)
        stack.pop();

      }
```

I have also checked "stackTemp!==". Any ideas? If something is unclear, sorry I will try to explain. 
Regards!

Comment: Use `while` loop instead of `do…while`?

Comment: and you can use `return` at anytime to break out of it

Comment: @Lissy i would use `break;` for this purpose, because if inside a function, `return` would exit the whole function instead of just the loop

Comment: I was doing something like that, I was using break, but i thought that there is no sense because of condition inside while, why this condition doesn't work, if stacktemp has got null why this loop still keep going till error?

Comment: `while(stackTemp = stackTemp.next) stack.push(stackTemp)` ..? and you definetly want `while(stackTemp)` and not the opposite.

Comment: this first version doesn't work still the same error;(, no matter what loop i would like to know why problem like that appears with do/while

Answer (score 2):

It seems that the comments are not enough to put you in the way, i'll then add explanations, with an addition of my own:

_Bergi suggests you use another syntax of `while` for a reason: `do{ /*code*/ }while(condition)` will execute the code at least once, regardless of the condition. You probably want to use `while(condition){ /*code*/ }` because with this syntax, you won't enter the loop if the condition fails, and your condition is "if a var value exists", you then don't want to enter if that fails.

_Amongst an another thing i won't explain (because i want to stay as clear as possible and that's a bit more advanced feature), Jonas W. remarks that your condition is wrong. While means "as long as". Your code tells to "stay in the loop as long as `stackTemp` is false (or empty, undefined, etc)". You probably want the contrary.

_Finally, it is useless to store `stackTemp.next` in `values` to place it in the array. You are not copying its value if it is an object (or function) because JS passes them by reference. You could just store `stackTemp.next` in the array, it will be the same, because `stackTemp` being replaced just after, its reference is changed and the `stackTemp.next` stored in the array will not be affected.

This would be the result, if it still doesn't work, that comes from something else:

```
stack.push(keys.head);
// visited.push(flag.data);
while(stack.size>0){
    stackTemp=stack.get()

    stack.pop();
    while (stackTemp){ //not supposed to enter here is stackTemp is empty
      stack.push(stackTemp.next);
      stackTemp=stackTemp.next; //stackTemp reference is replaced
      stack.show();
    }
    stackTemp=stack.get()
    // console.log(stackTemp);
    keyTemp=this.map.get(stackTemp.data);
    if(keyTemp=undefined)
    stack.pop();

}
```

Comment: Ehh, sorry guys, it seems that I'm a little bit tired, can't believe i couldn't see that, yep it went out from loop and after all cycle repeated again, at the second attempt it threw out error message, sorry for wasting time for such an easy issue, thanks!

Comment: No problem, glad we could help you!